# Issue with ftell and printing in utf-8

Tags: c, utf-8

I'm having two issues:
1) When testing this code, there's a few extra characters at the front of buf that are displayed. (When the file is empty, fsize is set to 3 for some reason).

2) The file contains utf-8 characters and are not displayed properly in console, I tried setting locale to LC_ALL and it didn't seem to have any effect.

```
void display_title(void)
{
    FILE *fh;
    char *buf;
    long fsize;

    fh = fopen("title.txt", "r");
    if (fh == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open title.txt for read\n");
        return;
    }

    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fh);
    rewind(fh);
    buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*fsize);

    fread(buf, fsize, 1, fh);
    fclose(fh);

    fwrite(buf, fsize, 1, stdout);
    free(buf);
}
```

**EDIT:** So I wrote a function to check the encoding of the file, somethings still off though. I have checked the file and I know it's UTF_8, but it's not registering in my function. I feel there is a bug somewhere, but I'm not seeing it.

```
// Check for BOM in file
// ERROR : file too small
// NONE : does not exist
// UTF_8_ENCODING : for utf_8 enoding found
// UTF_16_ENCODING : for utf_16 encoding found
// UTF_32_ENCODING : for utf_32 encoding found
int check_encoding(int fd)
{
    char *buf;
    off_t fsize;

    fsize = lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END);

    if (fsize < 2)
        return ERROR;

    buf = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, buf, 2);

    if (!strncmp(buf, UTF_16_BE, 2) ||
        !strncmp(buf, UTF_16_LE, 2))
    {
        free(buf);
        return UTF_16_ENCODING;
    }

    if (fsize >= 3)
    {
        realloc(buf, 3);

        if (!strncmp(buf, UTF_8, 3))
        {
            free(buf);
            return UTF_8_ENCODING;
        }
    }

    if (fsize >= 4)
     {
        realloc(buf, 4);

        if (!strncmp(buf, UTF_32_BE, 4) ||
            !strncmp(buf, UTF_32_LE, 4))
        {
            free(buf);
            return UTF_32_ENCODING;
        }
    }

    free(buf);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Certainly the 3 leading `char` is the BOM.  OP is reading the file in _text_ mode, yet using `fread()`, most useful for binary files.  `ftell()` "For a text stream ... the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read".  C11dr 7.21.9.4 2 Recommend opening the file in binary mode "rb".

Comment: Ignore the fact I used FILE ptr in the other function and descriptors in the check function. I changed it all to descriptors.

Comment: I'm also now using fsize = lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END) instead of ftell.

Comment: You _need_ to use `memcmp()`, not `strncmp()`.

Comment: Replace `realloc(buf, 3);` with `lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET); realloc(buf, 3); read(fd, buf, 3);`.  Similar with  `if (fsize >= 4)`.  Further, suggest, do not malloc, realloc, just make use `char buf[4]`

Comment: Thanks @chux this works great now! Actually tested on UTF 8 and 32 and both successful.

Comment: (I knew same named person who ran a restaurant)  There are a number of optimization opportunities here (e.g. no need to `lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END)`, just _attempt_ to read the first 4 bytes recording how much was read.  Likely a good solution exists in SO someplace all ready - if not - it is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell why UTF-8 is not diplayed properly on your console, but I think there is a simple reason for the three extra bytes at the beginning: most probably your file starts with a [Byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

**Edit**:
for UTF-8 encoded files, the BOM, if it exists, will always be the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. So if one wants to process files that may or may not contain a BOM, one can just read the first three bytes, check them for that value and ignore them if they are the BOM.

If you don't know the file's encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, ...), you can use the BOM to determine it. The wikipedia article I've linked to shows how it is represented in different encodings.

Comment: Is there a cross-platform way to handle BOM?

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. I'll try it now.